# How to iterate over custom properties?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I have a number of custom string properties that I added to my scene with:

```
bpy.types.Scene.prop1 = bpy.props.StringProperty()
bpy.types.Scene.prop2 = bpy.props.StringProperty()
# etc...
```

I want to be able to iterate over these properties to change their values.

I was hoping I would be able to do something like this:

```
for prop in bpy.types.Scene:
    prop = "new value";
```

This doesn't work but I would be iterating over all Scene properties instead of only mine anyway.

I also tried adding my properties' names to a list so that I might be able to access only my custom properties and not all the scene properties:

```
prop_names = ["prop1", "prop2", etc...]
```

But then I didn't know how to use these, I was hoping to do:

```
for prop in prop_names:
    bpy.types.Scene. + prop = "new value";
```

This also didn't work. So how might I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to use Python to inspect an objects properties, but in this case you're best off using `getattr`, `setattr`.

In the case you describe I think the best option is to store a list of properties,
mainly because there isn't a good way to know which properties **you** created. (Blender doesn't track a properties owner).

```
for prop_id in prop_names:
    setattr(scene, prop_id, value)
```

... for completeness, to copy `scene_src -> scene_dst`

```
for prop_id in prop_names:
    setattr(scene_dst, prop_id, getattr(scene_src, prop_id))
```

---

*Note, theres nothing spesific to custom propertes here, this is typical Python and world with **any** properties (called attributes in Python)*

Comment: Thanks, but using seattr is currently reporting in the console that my property is read-only?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, if you have read-only properties you need to either remove them from the list, or write more advanced code that handles them. For example `bpy.data.Object.modifiers` will report as readonly, not because you can't edit each modifier in the collection, you just cant assign the property directly, I assume you are getting this error on a `Collection` or `PointerProperty`. It would be best if you made a small example that fails for the purpose of this question.

Comment: I'm actually going to mark this question as solved, as your code does allow me to iterate over my properties as I wanted. I didn't realise having `bpy.types.Scene.my_prop="new_value"` after it's initial creation but before setattr would cause it to become read-only? I have now corrected this with bpy.context..instead of bpy.types.. but setattr makes this obsolete anyway. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, not sure your understanding properties correctly? - but I think it would be best to ask this as a separate question. `bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = "new_value"` is not something your normally would want to do.

Comment: It was more a facepalm moment than anything else, I'm probably not aware of all the facts when dealing with properties, but I think my mind just went blank when I was trying to assign to bpy.types...not a mistake I've made before ;)